# How to write Excel file by using String List

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I want to write a excel file. all writing details consist with a list. and set it as input parameter for the method.
Please tell me the best way to do this.

```
public static void writeExcelFile(List<String> combineLists){
          XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
          XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");
|
|

}
```

Input list:

[image]

Comment: Please [don't post text as image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1393766), post it as text (you can format it as code if you want to preserve formatting). Also can you describe [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Images says you have a list of string inside List where as your Input parameter has only list as a parameter. So I'll assume it is `List<List<String>>`

```
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("demo.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");
//I am creating and adding list just for illustration purpose only
            List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            l1.add(" l1 1");
            l1.add("l1 2");
            List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            l2.add(" l2 1");
            l2.add("l2 2");
            List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
            list.add(l1);
            list.add(l2);
            Iterator <List<String>>i = list.iterator();
            int rownum=0;
            int cellnum = 0;
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                List<String> templist = (List<String>) i.next();
                Iterator<String> tempIterator= templist.iterator();
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                cellnum = 0;
                while (tempIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String temp = (String) tempIterator.next();
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                                cell.setCellValue(temp);

                    }

                }
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
            workbook.close();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: how to write the same in column wise?